# bmatrix brackets too tall when using package setspacing and setting \doublespacing

Tags: spacing, brackets

Is there a way to get the brackets of the matrices to ignore the spacing that I set up for the paper? There is just a little too much space at the top of each matrix when using `\doublespacing`. I would like to keep the double spacing everywhere else as it makes the text nice and readable.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The answer to your question is almost certainly *yes* but it is also the case that no one will be able to tell you how to fix this problem unless you give is some details about the "spacing that I [you] set up for the paper". Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are doing: without code that exhibits your problem we have to guess what you are doing, which makes it almost impossible to help you. Your MWE should be as small as possible, it should compile and it should demonstrate your problem.

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm} \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}` has brackets that are just a little too tall. is there a way to have the brackets wrap around the contents the way they do when using `\singlespacing`

Comment: Please add a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) (MWE) to your *question*. A MWE should compile and contain the smallest amount necessary to demonstrate your problem.